# is it possible in salesforce apex to find out if community is enabled?

Tags: soql, community, appexchange

I am developing a managed package where i need to filter a user list where need to skip portal users.

I am trying to use isPortalEnabled field, which require community on the salesforce org.

so if package is deployed in an org where there is no community enabled in that case I need to check whether community is enabled or not, based on that I will use isPortalEnabled field in my soql query.

Comment: Have you tried just filtering on `ContactId != null` instead?

Answer (score 5):

You can check with the following code:

```
if(Type.forName('Schema.Network') != null) {
  // We have communities enabled!
```

As the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_network.htm) say:

> This object is available only if Salesforce Communities are enabled in your org.

Comment: I wanted to suggest `SELECT Id FROM Network` , but realized it wont even compile if communities is not enabled. Nice answer. +1